# Extract metadata from multiple images and store it in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract certain bits of metadata from .jpg images in a directory.
I am able to extract it form one image at a time with the following code:

```
    from PIL import Image, ExifTags
img = Image.open("C:../Inpex_Mangrove_test/Original_Photos/DSC_0056.JPG.JPG")
exif = { ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v for k, v in img._getexif().items() if k in ExifTags.TAGS }
md_list= [exif['Model'], exif['DateTimeDigitized']]#creates a list from the fields required
md_list
```

But I can not seem to be able to loop through and extract the code from all the images and store it in a list using this code:

```
   from PIL import Image, ExifTags
import glob

metadata =[]

def extract_metadata(filename):
    # extract metadata
    image = Image.open(filename)
    exif = { ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v for k, v in image._getexif().items() if k in ExifTags.TAGS }
    model = exif['Model']
    datetime =exif['DateTimeDigitized']#creates a list from the fields required          

    return model + '_' + datetime

# Loop through all jpeg files and create a list for metadatda extraction for each
for image_file in glob.glob("path/*.jpg"):
    md_file = extract_metadata(image_file)

    metadata.append((f"{image_file} {md_file}"))#convert output into a list

metadata
```

Thank you in advice for your help it is much appreciated.

Comment: What issue are you seeing, are you getting an error?

Comment: why do you have path/*.jpg? you need to include the full path or execute in the directory with the images and just use glob.glob("*.jpg")..

Comment: Thanks johnashu, that fixed it.